# How to ignore case when switching buffers?

Tags: buffers, case-folding

I want to open a buffer called `Echo.md` and `switch-buffer` (`C-x b`) does not auto-complete it when I type `echo` because of the case. But `find-file`  does auto-complete from lower-case to upper-case. The documentation for either function does not mention case.

How can Emacs ignore case when switching buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customize option `read-buffer-completion-ignore-case` to non-`nil`.

`C-h v read-buffer-completion-ignore-case` tells you:

> **`read-buffer-completion-ignore-case`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means completion ignores case when reading a buffer name.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 23.1 of Emacs.

---

Please consider filing a bug report (enhancement request), asking for the doc of `switch-to-buffer` and similar commands to mention the option: **`M-x report-emacs-bug`**.

I agree that it's not obvious.  I looked at the source code for that command and followed the trail backward through a few functions to finally stumble on the option. (Yes, I could have guessed there was such an option and tried `apropos` to find it.)

Comment: The documentation for `switch-to-buffer` says: "See `read-buffer' for features related to input and completion of buffer names."

Comment: This works, and extra credits for the `apropos` method to solve problems with a guess for the name of the solution. Given rpluim's comment, I won't file a bug report.